# Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid JETPACK COMPOSE

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to install jetpack compose in my android project. I was following this guide: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding

But when I tried to sync project,  I got the error in my gradle file:

```
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > plugin id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:android' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid

)
```

**here is the error occurs**

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:android' version '1.5.21'
    
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where `org.jetbrains.kotlin:android` did came from? It should be `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android`

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I copied it from the official guide from the link in my question `plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:android' version '1.5.21'`
}

Comment: I see, I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201628469) this documentation issue, please star it so it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks for the report, I'll make sure that gets fixed ASAP.  Currently we're double checking that we've got the minimum set of requirements right (such as whether `kotlinCompilerVersion` is actually necessary).  I've put an answer based on the current Compose template project in Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a mistake in the documentation.  I'm raising this internally and submitting a change to get it fixed.

In the meantime, you should instead simply ensure that you have the Kotlin Android plugin in your project:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

and then set the proper compiler version in the `composeOptions` block:

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.1'
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution
in
->build.gradle(Moudul project) add this line below

id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46.1' apply false