# setting up firebase on android studio plugin error

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to set up firebase and I am getting this error:

```
plugin id 'com.google.gms:google-services' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid)
```

This is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
  
}
```

I have put the plugins part after the dependencies as I read up the error, it was originally above dependencies.

This is how my gradle app looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms:google-services'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.farmapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.farmapplication"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I am unsure what else to change.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404217/plugin-id-contains-invalid-char-only-ascii-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: Yes that worked! I copied that code snippet directly from Firebase. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @iqram. You say "I copied that code snippet directly from Firebase". Did you get that from on of our documentation pages? If so, can you give a link to that page, so that we can fix it?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen. It was when I was connecting up the Firebase to my Android Studio project and gave instructions on how and what to copy in. I am guessing it won't direct you to the right place if I send a link.

Comment: Thanks. The URL of where you got the snippet from (or a screenshot of your screen at that point) would still be helpful though.